# Vue 2 + Element UI + Laravel 5.3 Starter

Tags: laravel-5.3, vuejs2

Anyone who is experienced to install Element UI on Laravel 5.3

http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/quickstart

Can anyone please help on the steps of installing it on Laravel 5.3? I am pretty new to it and not familiar with npm. Below is what I have done so far:

```
npm update vue
npm i element-ui -S
```

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-component": "^0.8.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.5",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-11",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.2.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "vue": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "element-ui": "^1.1.2",
    "toastr": "^2.1.2",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.2.3",
    "vue-timeago": "^3.1.2",
    "vue2.x-core-image-upload": "^0.9.2"
  }
}
```

In the component that I need to use element UI, for example:

Product-show.vue

```
<template>
  <el-select v-model="value" placeholder="Select">
    <el-option
      v-for="item in options"
      :label="item.label"
      :value="item.value">
    </el-option>
  </el-select>
</template>

<script>

import 'element-ui/lib/theme-default/index.css';
import { Button, Select } from 'element-ui';
  export default {
    components:{
      'el-button': Button,
      'el-select': Select
    },
    data(){
      return{
        product:[],
        productChoiceSelected:{},
        productChoices:[],
        img1:false,
        img2:false,
        img3:false,
        bxslider:{},
        options: [{
          value: 'Option1',
          label: 'Option1'
        }, {
          value: 'Option2',
          label: 'Option2'
        }, {
          value: 'Option3',
          label: 'Option3'
        }, {
          value: 'Option4',
          label: 'Option4'
        }, {
          value: 'Option5',
          label: 'Option5'
        }],
        value: ''
      }
    }
.....
.....
.....
  }
</script>
```

This is what I imagine I should do but of course it does not work for this newbie. Can someone help please?

EDIT#1

Console Log Error:

```
    1:1 Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: C:\xampp\htdocs\soyegg\node_modules\element-ui\lib\theme-default\index.css Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    | @charset "UTF-8";.el-breadcrumb:after,.el-breadcrumb:before,.el-form-item:after,.el-form-item:before,.el-form-item__content:after,.el-form-item__content:before{display:table;content:""}.el-slider__button,.el-slider__button-wrapper{-webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none}.el-alert,.el-dialog,.el-notification,.el-radio__inner,.el-switch__core{box-sizing:border-box}.el-pagination--small .arrow.disabled,.el-table td.is-hidden>*,.el-table th.is-hidden>*{visibility:hidden}.el-breadcrumb:after,.el-button-group:after,.el-form-item:after,.el-form-item__content:after,.el-menu:after,.el-pagination:after,.el-picker-panel__body-wrapper::after,.el-picker-panel__body::after,.el-row:after,.el-tabs__header:after{clear:both}.el-autocomplete__suggestions.is-loading li:after{display:inline-block;content:"";height:100%;vertical-align:middle}.el-button-group:after,.el-button-group:before{display:table;content:""}@font-face{font-family:element-icons;src:url(fonts/element-icons.eot?
........
........
........
........
l-collapse-item.is-active .el-collapse-item__header__arrow{-ms-transform:rotate(90deg);transform:rotate(90deg)}.el-collapse-item__header{height:43px;line-height:43px;padding-left:15px;background-color:#fff;color:#475669;cursor:pointer;border-bottom:1px solid #e0e6ed;font-size:13px}.el-collapse-item__header__arrow{margin-right:8px;transition:transform .3s}.el-collapse-item__wrap{will-change:height;background-color:#f9fafc;transition:height .3s cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1);overflow:hidden;box-sizing:border-box;border-bottom:1px solid #e0e6ed}.el-collapse-item__content{padding:10px 15px;font-size:13px;color:#1f2d3d;line-height:1.769230769230769}
        at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:655), <anonymous>:1:7)
        at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:655)
        at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
        at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:187), <anonymous>:1:97)
        at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:187)
        at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
        at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:125), <anonymous>:4:19)
        at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:125)
        at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
        at eval (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:273), <anonymous>:28:31)
    cdn.fontawesome.com/js/stats.js:1 Font Awesome CDN reporting has been enabled
```

Comment: Do you get any error, are you using webpack or anything for build?

Comment: @saurabh I think Laravel is using webpack. The error message on console log is hella long:

`Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: C:\xampp\htdocs\soyegg\node_modules\element-ui\lib\theme-default\index.css Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| @charset "UTF-8";.el-breadcrumb:after,.el............................ 10000words deleted, they seem to be the codes in index.css`

Comment: @saurabh updated the error, but it reached the words limit, here i simplify it. Hope it helps all of you to solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add you css loader config from webpack, was the code working before you added element-ui?

Comment: where should it be located? Yes all other codes work just fine without error before using element-ui

Comment: @saurabh did this ever get solved? I am also getting the "Unexpected character '@'..." error -- and my code was working before I added element-ui

Comment: sorry that I stopped using element UI since then so this question remained unsolved. Hope to see someone to input to revive.

Comment: hmmm, you might want to have a look into this issue https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/355. Are you using webpack2 ?

Comment: @iraklisg Yes correct, I am using webpack 2

Comment: @iraklisg yes but the issue seems remaining unsolved...

Comment: I am really looking for someone who can solve this issue as I stuck with JS problem while playing with bootstrap 4 in vue. Element UI seems to be good.

Answer (score 0):

Try  `npm install --save-dev css-loader` and  `npm install --save-dev style-loader`

Answer (score 0):

I too ran into this problem and as a workaround I copied the css from the node_modules folder and then pasted it directly into my project.

No doubt it has something to do with setting some kind of exception to allow the css-loader to parse the css from the node_modules but I didn't have time to mess with it.

Worked for me.